# Storing settings in Properties.Settings.Default vs the Registry

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, registry, settings

What is the difference between storing user settings for an application in

`Properties.Settings.Default`

versus storing it in the registry say

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\{Application Name}`

Comment: Could we make a requirement where, in order to mark a questions as a duplicate, you must select the question it duplicates so it can be linked here?  It's extremely frustrating to go back to the search and remember which questions were duplicates when trying to find the one that's not.

Answer (score 5):

**Properties.Settings.Default**

A common technique for storing application state between executions is to write it to disk. There are a wide variety of approaches for doing this and Microsoft jumped into the game by introducing the classes in System.Configuration namespace to help users manage saving application state (settings).

`Properties.Settings.Default` is a static instance of a class that derives from  [ApplicationSettingBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) which manages the reading and writing of settings to disk. Properties tagged with the `[UserScopedSetting]` attribute are saved to an XML file in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ComapnyName\Hashed_AppName\version which can be read and written to by the user. Properies tagged with the `[ApplicationScopedSetting]` attribute are saved to app.config file and can only be read.

A basic Settings file looks something like this:

```
class FormSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    public WindowSettings() {}
    public WindowSettings(string settingsKey) : base(settingsKey) {}

    [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [DefaultSettingValueAttribute("MyDefaultName")]
    public String Name
    {
        get { return (string)(this["Name"]); }
        set { this["Name"] = value; }
    }
}
```

You can set values in `Properties.Settings.Default` either in the UI, under Project Properties->Settings or programattically via `Properties.Settings.Default`.

**Registry**

The Registry is a hierarchical database that stores configuration settings and options and stores these them as key value pairs. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) for more information.

The registry can access be accessed through the static [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class which will allow you to read and write values. For example:

```
public class RegistryExample 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string rootUser = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
        const string subkey = "RegistryExample";
        const string keyName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}, rootUser, subkey);

        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "MyRegistryValue", 1234);
    }
}
```

See the MSDN documentation page for examples. As others have mentioned there are pros and cons to using the registry, but I think it's worth stating again that the registry is a "secure" location and your users will need permission to read a write from it where as a settings file does not require those permissions.

Comment: For the bottom example for the `const string keyName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}, userRoot, subkey);` I think you meant `rootUser` not `userRoot`

Comment: You are correct, answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the registry is, well, the registry. Whereas Properties.Settings.Default saves to a config file in your AppData directory.

I personally don't like working with the Registry at all. It's just a phobia I have left over from the Windows 98 era. It's not a nice experience working with the registry anyway. The key names are ugly and there's lots of potential for causing chaos.

Answer (score 1):

From [codehill.com](http://codehill.com/2009/01/saving-user-and-application-settings-in-winforms/):

> Before the .NET Framework application settings were saved in INI files
>   and the Windows Registry. But the .NET Framework introduced a much
>   easier way using an XML file. The file has the name of the Assembly
>   and a .exe.config extension, and is placed inside the application’s
>   folder. This way is cleaner because when an application is uninstalled
>   or deleted the end user does not have to worry about left over
>   registry keys or INI files in the Windows directory.

Answer (score 0):

Saving settings like Properties.Settings.Default is the one and only properly way to do it.

The registry is a no-go. You're not sure whether the user which uses your application, has sufficient rights to write to the registry.

Comment: Wouldn't you always have sufficient privileges to write to hkey_current_user from an installed application?

Comment: Well, theoretically you should have enough rights for HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Nevertheless it is surer to use a properly API.

Comment: Using the registry allows IT admins to easily deploy settings using Group Policies.